# I want to add row for each Regions with different measurement in PowerBI. Is it possible?

Tags: powerbi

I'm very new to PowerBI and I'm stuck with this problem for a while.

Suppose I have these two tables now:

**Table 1**

| Region |  | Whole Sale | Retail Sale | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Unit | 123 | 234 | 345 |
| B | Unit | 567 | 678 | 789 |

**Table 2**

| Region |  | Whole Sale | Retail Sale | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Share | 31.3 | 32.0 | 32.1 |
| B | Share | 19.3 | 19.1 | 18.9 |

I want to combine them and make it look this way:

| Region |  | Whole Sale | Retail Sale | YTD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Unit | 123 | 234 | 345 |
|  | Share | 31.3 | 32.0 | 32.1 |
| B | Unit | 567 | 678 | 789 |
|  | Share | 19.3 | 19.1 | 18.9 |

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for asking, is this a kind of assignment? What did you try and where did you get stuck? The easiest way is to **append** these 2 tables in PowerQuery.

Comment: I am sorry for the incomplete question. To add information, all the values on the unit row are in number of item while the share row are in percentage. 

I'm stuck at combining the first two table into one, but I see that the **append** function might help. I will try it and might come back if I'm stuck again. Thanks!